# Converting continuous streaming text into comma separated, multi-line file

Tags: file, unix, csv

I'm trying to convert a continuous stream of data (random) into comma separated and line separated values. I'm converting the continuous data into csv and then after some columns (let's say 80), I need to put a newline and repeat the process until.

Here's what I did for csv:

```
gawk '$1=$1' FIELDWIDTHS='4 5 7 1 9 5 10 6 8 3 2 2 8 4 8 8 4 6 9 1' OFS=, tmp
```

'tmp' is the file with following data:

`"ZaOAkHEnOsBmD5yZk8cNLC26rIFGSLpzuGHtZgb4VUP4x1Pd21bukeK6wUYNueQQMglvExbnjEaHuoxU0b7Dcne5Y4JP332RzgiI3ZDgHOzm0gjDLVat8au7uckM3t60nqFX0Cy93jXZ5T0IaQ4fw2JfdNF1PbqxDxXv7UGiyysFJ8z16TmYQ9zfBRCZvZirIyRboHNEGgMUFZ18y8XXCGrbpeL0WLstzpSuXetmo47G2xPkDLDcFA6cdM4WAFNpoC2ztspY7YyVsoMZdU7D3u3Lm6dDcKuJKdTV6600GkbLuvAamKGyzMtoqW3liI3ybdTNR9KLz2l7KTjUiGgc3Eci5wnhIosAUMkcSQVxFrZdJ9MVyj6duXAk0CJoRvHYuyfdAr7vjlwjkLkYPtFvAZp6wK3dfetoh3ZmhJhUxqzuxOLDQ9FYcvz64iuIUbgXVZoRnpRoNGw7j3fCwyaqCi..."`

I'm generating the continuous sequence from `/dev/urandom`. I'm not getting how to repeat the gawk after some column by adding a newline character after the column ends.

Answer (score 0):

I got it actually. A simple for loop did that.

Here's my whole code:

```
for i in $(seq 10)
do
    tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 < /dev/urandom | head -c 100 > tmp
    gawk '$1=$1' FIELDWIDTHS='4 5 7 1 9 5 10 6 8 3 2 2 8 4 8 8 4 6 9 1' OFS=, tmp >> tmp1
done
```

Any optimizations would be appreciated.